# Mongodb uses 100% CPU usage searching in more than 1M documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, find

I installed mongodb 4.4.3 on my ubuntu server(4 cores and 8GB of ram SSD) I have a collection of icons that contains more than 1M documents

On my backend I’m using node js and mongoose The problem is when I want to search in the icons collection, only one request uses 100% CPU, but the weird thing is that mongodb is still using the cpu 100% for about 10 seconds or so after delivering the response, I don’t understand why that

how can I fix this?

here is my code:

```
const icons = await Icon.find({name: ‘car’}).limit(100).lean();
```

Comment: Do you have index on the field `name`?

Comment: @PankajTanwar yes I created an index for the field name, but nothing changed.

Comment: How large is the collection as a whole (ie `db.collection.totalSize()`? 1 million documents might be a stretch on 8GB RAM if the database can't fit in memory. I don't remember the numbers exactly but I think the default memory allocation is something like 50% of memory minus 1GB, so in your case the process only has 3GB to work with.

Comment: MongoDB, in its default configuration, will use will use the larger of either 256 MB or ½ of (ram – 1 GB) for its cache size. Apart from this, please add the $explain output of your query.